# Loop through several values to fill NaNs in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I know that I cannot fill NaNs with a list, as stated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for `fillna`. What, then, is the preferred way to use a list of values to fill NaNs? Desired behaviour is to go through the list and fill NaNs one at a time; if there are more NaNs than in the list then start over. Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,100, 50))
s.loc[s > 25] = np.nan
s.fillna([10, 20, 30]) # Produces TypeError
```

Desired output:

```
0   10
1   20
2   30
3   10
4   20
5   9.0
6   30
7   21.0
8   10
```

etc.

Is this not built-in because it's difficult to vectorise? For what it's worth, this is just theoretical, I don't have actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to convert values to `NaN` first. So let's assume this starting point:

```
np.random.seed(0)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,100, 50))
```

Then you can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html):

```
mask = s > 25
s.loc[mask] = np.resize([10, 20, 30], mask.sum())
```

Alternatively, with [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
s = s.mask(s > 25, np.resize([10, 20, 30], len(s.index)))
```

Result:

```
print(s.head(10))
# 0    10
# 1    20
# 2    30
# 3    10
# 4    20
# 5     9
# 6    30
# 7    21
# 8    10
# 9    20
# dtype: int32
```

Comment: Second one is great, the first one doesn't work for me - leaves the series unchanged

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, Strange, both work fine for me with your input data.

Comment: OK, I realised my mistake - your method works before the assigning of NaNs. So it should be `mask = np.isnan(s)`

Comment: Other than that, thanks! I like it, it's more idiomatic than the other options.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, Yup, there's no need here to convert to `NaN` first, that's just an extra operation.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
s.loc[s.isna()]=[10,20,30]*(s.isna().sum()//3)+[10,20,30][:s.isna().sum()%3]
s
Out[271]: 
0     10.0
1     20.0
2     30.0
3     10.0
4     20.0
5      9.0
6     30.0
...
```